# how to install java application to another folder instead of ROOT

Tags: cloud-foundry

in clouldfoundry, How can I install a java application into webapps/abc, not webapps/ROOT?

If I push abc.war, I hope it can be extracted in webapps/abc, not webapps/ROOT

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, currently external URLs are not supported in CF. By external it mean the URL your app maps to should have to end with .cloudfoundry.com. If you installed vmc, which is the client command-line interface for CF, you can map your apps to multiple URLs with the following command:

```
vmc map <appname> <url>
```

If you try to map it to something like appname.cloudfoundry.com/subpath, you will get a error saying External URIs are not enabled.

You can go to http://support.cloudfoundry.com/forums/373013-feature-requests to raise it.

Answer (score 1):

Java apps are always installed as ROOT, such that they are afterwards accessible on "/". But of course, each app gets a different URL, namely **yourappname**.cloudfoundry.com. Why would you want to keep the "/abc/" part? Is it because the app has hardcoded "/abc/" urls in it? If so, you should make sure to construct your URLs properly, e.g. with `<c:url />` if using JSP for example.